# Translate store language label in magento frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, magento-community, inline-translations

I wish to translate store language switcher label dropdown from english to simplified chinese.
PFA for thes same.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml` into your theme

add below code

```
 echo $this->__(<Text to translate>);
```

you want to translate

```
$this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName())
```

so

```
$this->__($this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()))
```

Your final code

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Your Language:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->__($this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName())) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Add entry in csv file for translation**

Answer (score 0):

i have this in 2.4 how to translate the string:

getStores()) > 1): ?>

```
<?php $id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : '' ?>
<div class="switcher language switcher-language" data-ui-id="language-switcher"
     id="switcher-language<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
     echo $id ?>">
    <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Language') ?></span></strong>
    <div class="switcher-content">
        <div class="action-switcher" id="switcher-language-trigger<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $id ?>">
            <div class="heading-switcher view-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentStoreCode()) ?>"
                 style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                 echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/flags/flag_' . $block->getCurrentStoreCode() . '.svg') ?>');">
                <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreName()) ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown-switcher">
            <ul class="list-item">
                <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
                    <?php if ($_lang->getId() != $block->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
                        <li class="view-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()); ?> switcher-option">
                            <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            echo $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>'>
                            <span style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/flags/flag_' . $_lang->getCode() . '.svg') ?>');"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```